# Comparing substrings in same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to run a query that will give me the list of all entries in one column that is NOT LIKE any of the entries in another column, i.e.:

```
SELECT DISTINCT columnA
FROM tableA
WHERE columnA NOT LIKE (SELECT columnB FROM tableA)
```

Obviously, the above query doesn't work, I'm providing it only in the hopes that it will clarify what I'm trying to achieve. So, as an example, say that my columns contain the following:

```
COLUMNA:
ABCD
ABCE
BCDE
BCDF
BCDEF
GHIJ
GHIK

COLUMNB:
ABC
DEF
HIJ
```

My desired results would be:

```
BCDE
BCDF
GHIK
```

There are a total of 396 values in column in the table, so just entering the values manually is not feasible. In addition, as noted in the example, the values in columnB would always be substrings of the values in columnA, so I also need to have my query do the comparison with that in mind.

Thanks in advance for any help anyone can offer, and also apologies if this question has already been answered elsewhere - I did a search but wasn't able to find anything that I could interpret as addressing this specific requirement.

ADDING NEW INFO ****

So, as noted, I made a HUGE mistake in that the two columns are in different tables. That said, though, it was easy enough to modify califax's suggestion below as follows:

SELECT DISTINCT COLUMNA
FROM TABLE1 T1
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON
T1.COLUMNA LIKE '%' + T2.COLUMNB + '%'
AND T2.COLUMNB IS NULL

However, it's still returning the full list of entries from COLUMNA. I've confirmed that there are entries in COLUMNB that are substrings of the entries in COLUMNA - any ideas why this isn't filtering?

Thanks.

Comment: If you are just comparing columns with no wild card then use =.  It will not spend time parsing the data for wild cards.

Comment: Thanks Blam - I'm actually comparing wild cards, since the values in COLUMNB, if they exist in COLUMNA values, exist as substrings, not exact matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perform a self join, and look for the ones that don't match:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a1.ColumnA 
FROM TableA a1
LEFT JOIN TableA a2
ON a1.ColumnA LIKE '%' + a2.ColumnB + '%'
AND a2.ColumnB IS NULL
```

(I added a leading wildcard, since you clarified the desired matches in your question.)

UPDATE

If there are two distinct tables, b.ColumnB shows you the ones that don't match:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.ColumnA 
FROM TableA a
LEFT JOIN TableB b
ON a.ColumnA LIKE '%' + b.ColumnB + '%'
AND b.ColumnB IS NULL
```

Comment: @critifax. Thanks. This is exactly the query I ran. For some reason, it's not doing the filtering. I can't understand why, because this query makes absolute sense to me, and should be working. One question - it shouldn't make any difference if one of the tables is INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS, should it?

Comment: Okay, thanks. I can't figure out why this isn't working. As I said, I completely understand the query, and it makes absolute sense to me that it should work. Looks like I'll have to do it manually w/Excel and VLOOKUP. Thanks, though, appreciate everyone's help.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT DISTINCT columnA
FROM tableA as O
WHERE not exists ( select 42 from TableA where O.ColumnA like ColumnB )
```

Answer (score 2):

I would try something like :

```
select distinct columnA from tableA where columnA not like '%' + columnB + '%'
```

or following criticalfix's remark (as I'm not sure what you wish exactly)

```
SELECT DISTINCT columnA FROM tableA tbA
WHERE not exists ( select 1 from TableA where tbA.ColumnA like '%' + ColumnB '%' )
```

Comment: Doesn't that just check whether ColumnA matches ColumnB within the same record?  I think OP is looking for a ColumnB match anywhere in the table, is that right?

Comment: Indeed, I'm not sure what OP wants. I've edited it with what I think is a proper solution for that case. Your solution seems OK though, and cleaner (although I'm not a big fan of joins in that case cause I find it less readable), so I will upvote it...

Comment: @criticalfax. That is right - anywhere the value of an entry in columnB appears in the value of columnA as a substring, I don't want the value in columnA in my results. But it turns out I made a HUGE mistake in my original description - the two columns are NOT in the same table. Not sure why I was thinking they were, apologies for that. Not sure at this point if the right approach is to edit the original description, or create a new help request and link to it from here.

Comment: don't do anything but accept one of the solutions (I would suggest criticalfix's solution). The fact that the 2 columns are in separate tables isn't a problem, you can still use the solution, just adapt the table names...

Comment: Thanks Bartdude. I did in fact try critifax's solution - it made perfect sense, and it turns out that all I really needed to know was how to construct the string (i.e., the '%' + table2.columnB + '%'). But for some reason, the results aren't filtering out the matches. Very strange. I'll add the actual modified query to another entry and see if anyone has any ideas.